# How can the anonymous user workflow for the landing page be improved?

Tags: discussion, design, new-users

**The interesting section**

When I visit the landing page (https://stackoverflow.com) it leverages a set of knowledge to provide me with interesting questions. I actually like that set, to be honest. However, when you are not logged in (using chrome incognito is a good way to view this without having to log out), that section has nothing to leverage. I think it just takes the first set of active questions.

[image]

Perhaps this is just me, but a question about VBA with 2 views is not really that thrilling. At the very least, this tab should be named what it really is, "active", but more than likely it should simply be removed and instead replaced with one of the other more advertisey tabs (featured, hot, etc).

- *96.* [image]

96.... That is how many "interesting" questions (labelled as Top Questions) are listed. Not only is this going to slow down page load time, it makes absolutely no sense as there is no link to the user wanting to see any of those posts (re: no data), and also the main goal of this page is to get them to signup.

**The ask question button**

The "Ask Question" button is clickbait. It takes you to the log in or signup page, even though there are already two places to sign up and one to log in present on the page.

- *redirected page* [image: separate login/signup page]
- *existing links to signup or login* [image: highlighted login/signup links]

While I understand that it is an important aspect of the site to provide an entry into asking a question, it should be more obvious that an account is going to be required in order to do so. And if not, at the very least the ask question link should go directly to sign up.

**What can be done**

Seemingly, the goal here is to get new users to sign up or at least enter the site. At present, it feels like that could be improved. I think that there are opportunities in the interesting section and with the ask question button.

So how can this page be improved?

Comment: I wonder how many first visits to SO are a direct visit to the main page vs. to a specific question from google.

Comment: @AlonEitan Not many: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/ 1.31% of visits (when automated traffic is filtered out)

Comment: Thank you @hairboat - I'm amazed by the amount of scraping going on SO, but apart from that and based on the statistics - It seems like this question is about a niche  scenario, as most anonymous users first find a solution here, and only then converting as registered users?

Comment: @AlonEitan - That is correct, this is not a massive magnet as far as traffic goes. A vast majority of traffic comes in to direct urls. It is however, sort of the "public face" that Stack Overflow has, and it seems like there could be room for improvements. As to your point about finding a solution, and then converting, I am not sure what that route's statistics are. For example, do most users who want to register then visit the landing page and then register, do they find it through an interactive button (most likely), or do they directly click on sign up?

Comment: 1.31% of all stackoverflow visits is still a lot of visits, due to amount of traffic in SO. I can't agree that front page of a site this big is a niche scenario. We have plenty of questions and discussions on use cases that are a *lot* more niche.

Comment: Note that it was 2 views in the first 22 seconds of the question's existence.

Comment: On the bright side, at least the current setup gives the new arrivals an honest depiction of what the majority of SO's questions are like: boring debugging questions written in broken English.

Comment: @MarkAmery not sure that qualifies as "bright"